# Conditional compilation in Python

Tags: python, conditional-compilation

How to do conditional compilation in Python ?

Is it using DEF ?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean by "conditional compilation" and how you would actually use it in an actual Python program.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python isn't compiled in the same sense as C or C++ or even Java, python files are compiled "on the fly", you can think of it as being similar to a interpreted language like Basic or Perl.<sub>1</sub>

You can do something equivalent to conditional compile by just using an if statement. For example:

```
if FLAG:
    def f():
        print "Flag is set"
else:
    def f():
        print "Flag is not set"
```

You can do the same for the creation classes, setting of variables and pretty much everything.

The closest way to mimic IFDEF would be to use the hasattr function. E.g.:

```
if hasattr(aModule, 'FLAG'):
    # do stuff if FLAG is defined in the current module.
```

You could also use a try/except clause to catch name errors, but the idiomatic way would be to set a variable to None at the top of your script.

1. Python code is byte compiled into an intermediate form like Java, however there generally isn't a separate compilation step. The "raw" source files that end in .py are executable.

Comment: Is there something like ifdef ?

Comment: Pragmatically true, but technically false.  Python IS compiled in the same sense as Java, however the compilation step is not made explicit to the programmer.

Comment: @Arafangion:
Straight to the point... why don't you expand this a [tiny] little bit in an answer?

Comment: @rejinacm: ifdef is an old idiom from C anyway. Why should python have it? it doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is not the same at all.  When you compile out a conditional, there is absolutely no way that the conditional code can be executed when released.  What you have here, is some dormant code that exists based on some conditional that could be activated through modification of the environment.  This may not be desirable for any form of production code.  That said, the c-preprocessor is actually just a text processor and works with many languages.  You could try it with python.  It works well with CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 22):

There is actually a way to get conditional compilation, but it's very limited.

```
if __debug__:
    doSomething()
```

The `__debug__` flag is a special case.  When calling python with the `-O` or `-OO` options, `__debug__` will be false, and the compiler will ignore that statement.  This is used primarily with asserts, which is why assertions go away if you 'really compile' your scripts with optimization.

So if your goal is to add debugging code, but prevent it from slowing down or otherwise affecting a 'release' build, this does what you want.  But you cannot assign a value to `__debug__`, so that's about all you can use it for.

Answer (score 19):

Use [pypreprocessor](http://github.com/evanplaice/pypreprocessor/)

Which can also be found on [PYPI (Python Package Index)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypreprocessor) and can be fetched using pip.

The basic example of usage is:

```
from pypreprocessor import pypreprocessor

pypreprocessor.parse()

#define debug

#ifdef debug
print('The source is in debug mode')
#else
print('The source is not in debug mode')
#endif
```

You can also output the postprocessed code to a file by specifying...

```
pypreprocessor.output = 'output_file_name.py'
```

anywhere between the pypreprocessor import and the call to parse().

The module is essentially the python implementation of C preprocessor conditional compilation.

*SideNote: This is compatible with both python2x and python 3k*

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of pypreprocessor*

**Update:**

I forgot to mention before. Unlike the `if`/`else` or `if _debug:` approaches described in other answers, this is a true preprocessor. The bytecode produced will not contain the code that is conditionally excluded.

Answer (score 4):

Python compiles a module automatically when you import it, so the only way to avoid compiling it is to not import it. You can write something like:

```
if some_condition:
  import some_module
```

But that would only work for complete modules. In C and C++ you typically use a preprocessor for conditional compilation. There is nothing stopping you from using a preprocessor on your Python code, so you could write something like:

```
#ifdef SOME_CONDITION
def some_function():
  pass
#endif
```

Run that through a C preprocessor and you'd have real conditional compilation and `some_function` will only be defined if `SOME_CONDITION` is defined.

BUT (and this is important): Conditional compilation is probably not what you want. Remember that when you import a module, Python simply executes the code in it. The def and class statements in the module are actually *executed* when you import the module. So the typical way of implementing what other languages would use conditional compilation for is just a normal if statement, like:

```
if some_condition:
  def some_function():
    pass
```

This will only define `some_function` if `some_condition` is true.

It's stuff like this that makes dynamic languages so powerful while remaining conceptually simple.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't make much sense in a dynamic environment. If you are looking for conditional definition of functions, you can use `if`:

```
if happy:
    def makemehappy():
        return "I'm good"
```

Comment: The problem is that it does not work if happy is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method discussed here: [Determine if variable is defined in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592565/determine-if-variable-is-defined-in-python) as a substitute for `#ifdef`