# conditional evaluation of source file in python

Tags: python

Say I have a file that's only used in pre-production code

I want to ensure it gets not run in production code- any calls out to it have to fail.

This snippet at the top of the file doesn't work - it breaks the Python grammar, which specifies that `return` must take place in a function.

```
if not __debug__:
   return None
```

What is the best solution here - the one that doesn't involve making a gigantic else, that is. :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
if not __debug__:
    raise RuntimeError('This module must not be run in production code.')
```

Comment: The kicker is, I want the module to be "empty" when in production mode. Raising an error is not the right answer here.

Comment: Ahh, apparently I misunderstood your question.  Then I think the best choice is the gigantic `if`.  I would probably use `if __debug__:`, put everything you want in there, and then you don't need an `else`.  I realize you want to avoid this sort of thing, however :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe split the non-production code out into a module which is conditionally imported from the main code?

```
if __debug__:
    import non_production
    non_production.main()
```

Updated: Based on your comment, you might want to look a 3rd-party library [pypreprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/pypreprocessor/) which lets you do C-style preprocessor directives in Python. They provide [a debugging example](http://code.google.com/p/pypreprocessor/source/browse/examples/debug.py) which seems very close to what you're looking for (ignoring inline debug code without requiring indentation).

Copy/pasted from that url:

```
from pypreprocessor import pypreprocessor
pypreprocessor.parse()
#define debug

#ifdef debug
print('The source is in debug mode')
#else
print('The source is not in debug mode')
#endif
```

Comment: That's likely to be the solution, but I am hoping to avoid creating two different files for what amounts to an `#ifdef`.

Comment: @Paul Also check out http://code.google.com/p/pypreprocessor/source/browse/examples/debug2production.py. It demonstrates how to use command line arguments to manipulate the #defines when you execute the script (Ie, the defines are stored in a python list and can be changed in code). That should eliminate the need to create multiple source files. Also, if you get a feel for it, there's a way to output the post-processed code do a file if, for some reason, you need a production-only version.  Note: I'm the author of pypreprocessor so if you need any more info feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

if not __debug__:
    sys.exit()
```

Documentation for [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to hide all of the stuff in that module in another module that is imported conditionally.

```
.
├── main.py
├── _test.py
├── test.py
```

main.py:

```
import test
print dir(test)
```

test.py:

```
if __debug__:
    from _test import *
```

_test.py:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

**Edit**:

Just realized your comment in another answer where you said "I am hoping to avoid creating two different files for what amounts to an #ifdef". As shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560040/conditional-compilation-in-python), there really isn't any way to do what you want without an if statement.

I've upvoted the answer by samplebias, as I think that answer (plus edit) describes the closest you're going to get without using an if statement.